# How to upload the update-request.txt file in mend for SCA scan

Tags: security, penetration-testing, penetration-tools, sca

Completed the offline Software composition analysis scan on the application and got the update-request.txt file.

How to upload that text file into mend to get the results?

Got the update-request.txt file. How to upload into mend tool.